# Getting data with diferent currencies from Bloomberg API,using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, bloomberg

I am trying to extract data from Bloomberg.
I need data for multiple fields with diferent currencies.
I can't get what I need from this answer https://github.com/alpha-xone/xbbg

Can anyone help, please?. for a "specifc time" and on a "period of time"?

I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
blp.bdh(
       tickers='TPXDDVD Index,SCTOGAA LN Equity,VAPEJSI ID Equity', flds=['PX_LAST', 'FUND_NET_ASSET_VAL', 'FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS'],
     start_date='2018-10-01', end_date='2019-11-01', FX=['JPY','GBp','USD']
    )
```

Comment: I don't think you can provide an array of overrides. You probably need to group your tickers by currency and send one request per currency. Also if you just need the pricing currency then you don't need the override at all.

Comment: @assylias could you please ellaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: If you request PX_LAST on "IBM US Equity", you will receive a price in USD by default - so it's only if you want a currency that is different from the instrument "default" currency that you need to use the FX override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to group similar securities together when pulling in historic data. In the OP's question, 'TPXDDVD Index' is a calculated total return index. Hence it will not have the same fields available as the other two, which as their tickers suggest are quoted funds.

Taking just the two quoted funds, `SCTOGAA LN Equity` and `VAPEJSI ID Equity`, we can determine the default currency in which each field is denominated. This being Bloomberg, naming conventions are organic and may not be obvious! The two value fields are `FUND_NET_ASSET_VAL` and `FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS`, and the default currency might be different for each.

We can use the `bdp()` function to pull back these currencies as follows (NB tickers are in a python list:

```
from xbbg import blp

tickers = ['SCTOGAA LN Equity','VAPEJSI ID Equity']
df = blp.bdp(tickers,['NAV_CRNCY','FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS_CRNCY'])
print(df)
```

With the result:

```
                  nav_crncy fund_total_assets_crncy
SCTOGAA LN Equity       GBp                     GBP
VAPEJSI ID Equity       USD                     EUR
```

So for VAPEJSI *the NAV and Total Assets are denominated in different currencies*. And NB. `GBp` is not a typo by the data entry clerk, it means `GBP pence`.

You can override the currency with a **single currency value** applied to all fields in the function call.

```
from xbbg import blp
    
fields = ['FUND_NET_ASSET_VAL','FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS']

df = blp.bdh('SCTOGAA LN Equity',fields,
             start_date='2018-10-01', end_date='2019-11-01')

print(df.tail(2))

df = blp.bdh('SCTOGAA LN Equity',fields,
             start_date='2018-10-01', end_date='2019-11-01', Currency='USD')

print(df.tail(2))
```

which returns:

```
            SCTOGAA LN Equity
           FUND_NET_ASSET_VAL FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS
2019-10-31              70.81           1755.65
2019-11-01              70.99           1756.51
            SCTOGAA LN Equity
           FUND_NET_ASSET_VAL FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS
2019-10-31            0.91607        2271.28527
2019-11-01            0.91840        2272.40325
```

The asset value in GBP pence, has been converted to USD dollars. As an aside if you had put `Currency='USd'` instead you would have the price in US cents. You have to love case-sensitivity ...